# How do I fix the indentation error of 4 line?

Tags: python

```
ch = input("Enter a character: ")
try:
if(ch=='A' or ch=='a' or ch=='E' or ch =='e' or ch=='I' or ch=='i' or ch=='O' or ch=='o' or ch=='U' or ch=='u'):
    print(ch, "is a Vowel")
else:
    print(ch, "is a consonant")
except TypeError:
    print ("Data type error occurred, Please provide any positive number to calculate factorial of it.")
```

Comment: its a try block, you have to put the if and else block inside the try block

Comment: Make sure to use either tabs or spaces of equal length for indentation. Don't use both in the same file.

Comment: Basically, any line that ends in `:`, the next line has to be indented

Comment: At first you have to fix your code snippet, so we can your indentation. Hint: mark the code and use the `{}` button!

Answer (score 1):

The inside of a try block has to be indented; basically any time a line ends with `:`, the next line will need to be indented.

```
ch = input("Enter a character: ")
try:
    if(ch=='A' or ch=='a' or ch=='E' or ch =='e' or ch=='I' or ch=='i' or ch=='O' or ch=='o' or ch=='U' or ch=='u'):
        print(ch, "is a Vowel")
    else:
        print(ch, "is a Consonant")
except TypeError:
    print ("Data type error occured, Please provide any positive number to calculate factorial of it.")
```